# how to verify the content of a list and return the values using robot framework

Tags: list, robotframework

I'm suddenly stock to this scenario, wherein i can't verify and return the value of a list using Robot framework.[this is the list am talking about](https://i.stack.imgur.com/efqz7.png). In selenium ide i can just simply verifytext and then the value will be verified but how can i apply it in robot framework?

I tried initializing a variable which consists of the values inside the list but it returns error (saying that it doesn't match... since the values in the list is separated by nextline).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Show us your code, we can't tell what you've missed if we don't even know what you've done exactly.

Answer (score 0):

I just used the element should contain keyword`element should contain   locator    values`
if values are more than 1 you can separate it using \n ex. `value1\n value`